# iteration issue, inner substraction does not work properly

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
df2={'ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON':['000053','00012','00014'],
     'stock':[10,23,99]
      }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data=df2)

'''
talep={'FHY Sicil':['FB00662','FB003208'],
     'Şube Kodu':['00014','00014'],
    'adet':[50,50]
      }
talep= pd.DataFrame(data=talep)
'''
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
lst=[]
for i in range(len(talep)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if talep.iloc[i]['Şube Kodu']==df2.iloc[j]['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON']:
            if  df2.iloc[j]['stock']>=talep.iloc[i]['adet']:
                lst.append([talep.iloc[i]['FHY Sicil'],talep.iloc[i]['Şube Kodu'],talep.iloc[i]['adet']])
                df2.iloc[j]['stock']=df2.iloc[j]['stock']-talep.iloc[i]['adet']
                break
            elif df2.iloc[j]['stock']<talep.iloc[i]['adet'] and  df2.iloc[j]['stock']>0:  
                lst.append([talep.iloc[i]['FHY Sicil'],talep.iloc[i]['Şube Kodu'],df2.iloc[j]['stock']])
                #print(df2.iloc[j]['stock'])
                df2=df2[~(df2['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON']==df2.iloc[j]['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON'])]
                break
                #df2.iloc[j]['stock']=0
                #df2.iloc[j]['stock']=df2.iloc[j]['stock']-talep.iloc[i]['adet']
                #print(df2['stock'])
final = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['FHY Sicil','Şube Kodu','adet'])

final.sort_values(by=['Şube Kodu']).head(3)
```

1. Stock for 00014 is 99, however in total 100 is delivered for FB006620 and FB003208. Each gets 50.
2. `df2.iloc[j]['stock']=df2.iloc[j]['stock']-talep.iloc[i]['adet']` >> I need to show the remaining amount after first iteration. i.e., since 50 is given to   FB006620, remaining 49 should be given to FB003208.

Comment: Your code issues a warning.  Did you see it? `df2.iloc[j]` returns a copy of the data, not on the actual data, so you're not changing the actual table.  Do you really need pandas for this?  Because it looks like it's getting in the way.

Comment: You can make this work by fixing the indexing.  Instead of df2.iloc[j]['stock'], use df2['stock'][j], and the same throughout.  You  don't need iloc at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2={'ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON':['000053','00012','00014'],
     'stock':[10,23,99]
      }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data=df2)

talep={'FHY Sicil':['FB00662','FB003208'],
     'Sube Kodu':['00014','00014'],
    'adet':[50,50]
}
talep= pd.DataFrame(data=talep)

lst=[]

for i, tt in talep['Sube Kodu'].items():
    for j, dd in df2['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON'].items():
        if dd == tt:
            if df2['stock'][j]>=talep['adet'][i]:
                lst.append([talep['FHY Sicil'][i],tt,talep['adet'][i]])
                df2['stock'][j]-=talep['adet'][i]
            elif df2['stock'][j]<talep['adet'][i] and  df2['stock'][j]>0:  
                lst.append([talep['FHY Sicil'][i],tt,df2['stock'][j]])
                df2=df2[~(df2['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON']==df2.iloc['ATANAN_ORGANIZASYON'][j])]
        break
final = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['FHY Sicil','Sube Kodu','adet'])

final.sort_values(by=['Sube Kodu']).head(3)

print(final)
```